# JavaScript: How do use instance variables

Tags: javascript, oop

why doesn't this work as expected. (see expected comment)

```
var Module = function () {
    var public_instance_var;

    function doStuff () {
        Module.doOtherStuff();
        console.log(public_instance_var); // expected: true, but logs undefined
    };

    function doOtherStuff() {
        public_instance_var = true;
    };

    return {
        public_instance_var: instance_var,
        doStuff: doStuff,
        doOtherStuff: doOtherStuff
    }
}();

Module.doStuff();
```

*Update:* Fixed accordingly to a few of jAndy suggestions

Comment: seems like you missed instance_var

Comment: Is there a typo in the return? where is instance_var defined?

Comment: `Module.doStuff();` should throw the error that `Module` does not have a callable property `doStuff` (or similar). The line with your comment is never executed. Also, this really does not have anything to do with OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors here:

- You don't return `DoStuff` as module interface
- `instance_var` is not declared, probably meant `public_instance_var`
- `doOtherStuff` is never assigned to `Module`, just call it like `doOtherStuff();`

Fixed code:

```
var Module = function () {
    var public_instance_var;

    function doStuff() {
        doOtherStuff();
        console.log(public_instance_var); // expected: true, but logs undefined
    };

    function doOtherStuff() {
        public_instance_var = true;
    };

    return {
        doStuff: doStuff,
        public_instance_var: public_instance_var
    }
}();

Module.doStuff();
```

Comment: public_instance_var : instance_var reveals a public pointer to the private property public_instance_var and is thus correct in my code. The rest of your observation seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

change your code like so

```
var Module = function () {
    var public_instance_var;

    function doStuff () {
        doOtherStuff();
        console.log("var is ", public_instance_var); // expected: true, but logs undefined
    };

    function doOtherStuff() {
        public_instance_var = true;
    };

    return {
        public_instance_var: public_instance_var,
        doStuff : doStuff
    }
}();

Module.doStuff();
```

- you have to return `doStuff()` function (otherwise outside it will be undefined) and `public_instance_var` instead of `instance_var`
- you need to execute `doOtherStuff()` without prefixing `Module.`

Answer (score 0):

What this code does is, simply put: create and run a function and assign its return value to a variable: `Module`. The return value is an object with 1 property: `public_instance_var`, that points to the variable `instance_var`, or (after correcting the typo: `public_instance_var`). This variable was declared, but not instantiated. Therefore the return value looks like this:

```
Module.public_instance_var = undefined
```

The very last line `Module.doStuff();` won't work one bit: Module is an object that has no methods. The functions you declared are garbage collected when the anonymous function returns. If you want access to those functions, you'll need to include them in the return statement. Read up on closures, Object constructors and design patterns in general, but I'd say the code you're after will look something like this:

```
var Module = (function()
    var public_instance_var;
    function doStuff () {
        this.doOtherStuff();
        console.log(public_instance_var); // expected: true, but logs undefined
    };
    function doOtherStuff() {
        public_instance_var = true;
    };
    return {
        public_instance_var: public_instance_var,
        doStuff: doStuff,
        doOtherStuff: doOtherStuff
    };
})();
```

Of course, this way your variable `public_instance_var` is a public property, so my guess would be what you're really trying to do is simulate a private properties and methods. In which case you might end up with code similar to this:

```
var Module = (function()
{
    var public_instance_var;
    return {
        //public_instance_var: public_instance_var, remove this line
        //the closure will preserve access to the variable
        doStuff: function ()
        {
            this.doOtherStuff();//this, you're referencing the object's property
            console.log('here I am');
        },
        doOtherStuff: function ()
        {
            public_instance_var = true;
            //this won't work anymore:
            //this.public_instance_var = true;
        };
    }
})();
```

`Module.doStuff()` now logs `here I am`, but the `doOtherStuff` is now a public method, too. Here's how you might choose to solve the issue:

```
var Module = (function()
{
    var public_instance_var;
    function doOtherStuff ()
    {
        public_instance_var = true;
    };
    return {
        //public_instance_var: public_instance_var, remove this line
        //the closure will preserve access to the variable
        doStuff: function ()
        {
            doOtherStuff();//don't use this here, but the reference to the function exists thanks to closure
            console.log('here I am');
            console.log(public_instance_var);//logs true
        }
    };
})();
```

These are just a few of the very powerful things you can do with closures and functions returning objects. 
Just read a couple of articles, like [this](http://higher-order.blogspot.be/2008/02/javascript-parasitic-inheritance-super.html) one, there are better ones out there. Google the term `power constructors`